# AutoMapping between the Same Enum C#

Tags: c#, enums, automapper, automapping

I have this auto mapper that is mapping enum type,

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SASEMProfileVm, SASEMMembersDto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ProfessionalHistoryDto.CarryingTime, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProfessionalHistoryCarryingTime))
```

CarryingTime is of type TimePeriod and ProfessionalHistoryCarryingTime is also from type TimePeriod

when i run it it gives me this error

> Expression 'dest => Convert(dest.ProfessionalHistoryDto.CarryingTime)'
>   must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's
>   properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap
>   option instead. Parameter name: lambdaExpression

What should i do to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper cannot define mapping for multilevel objects. You can use .AfterMap

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SASEMProfileVm, SASEMMembersDto>()
      .AfterMap((s, d) => 
          d.ProfessionalHistoryDto.CarryingTime = s.ProfessionalHistoryCarryingTime);
```